# Unity for PS Vita

Tags: unity-game-engine, sony, playstation

With the end of the PSM program ending, how does one Sony plan to support development of games in Unity for the Vita? Do I apply to the regular development program? Is it still as open/simple? Can I still use a retail Vita to test?

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you will not be able to use the regular retail kits even as test devices. There is a connection process between PSM developer key and your PS Vita which will no longer work after May 31st.

If at all possible you will want to get your hands on a development kit for PS3/PS3/PS Vita - this will allow you to use Unity on these platforms.  Please note that Unity will require authorisation from Sony before releasing their plugin for Unity that allows you to target Sony platforms.

Comment: First, that is rather unfortunate. Why Is Sony screwing the indie scene on this? I've been working on an indie game for the last few months that would be awesome to see on the Vita, and now Ill have to buy an EXPENSIVE dev kit to do so...  Second, until then, how do I get the ps vita "module" loaded in Unity 5.? It is not on the list of modules...

Comment: You wont be able to get the Unity5 module for PS Vita unless you are a registered Sony developer. That means signing their NDA and purchasing a dev kit.

It may be worth considering the continued development of your game using Unity then taking your game to a publisher or game developer that has access to a PS Vita dev kit. I, myself, work for a University that teaches Games Programming as an award, perhaps there are some universities and colleges near you that would be interested in working with you to get the game published on Vita.

Comment: Well, that really sucks..... Thanks for the info! I guess Ill just have to do what ive been doing, which is to use a ps2 controller to 'simulate' vita-like controls...

Comment: No Problem, glad to have helped. Sorry it wasn't the answer you were hoping for. I wouldn't be surprised if Sony have another offering to Indy devs in future - I expect the lifecycle of the PS4 to be quite significant and if you remember Microsoft's XNA at all it went through a couple of iterations on XBox before they got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is wrong as you can install Testkit modules to vs0 on a Modified 3.60+ Retail unit, all you need is a "CEX/DEX" Converter, there are a few, then you need plugins from Autoplugin homebrew, that will contain plugins that allow to reactivate PSM and decryption of Psm applications, there are a couple other related changes but all will be clear if you look for it on the Autoplugin.vpk  / github / modding forums, also Twitter developers do a lot of great work for the scene! Sony can have all the backing for official Sdk development they want it wont stop developers from doing there thing! :) practice is everything!

There are also leaked keys for unity PS modules, but this is best with official resources etc it probably could produce issues

Comment: Also there are plenty of refurbished / old test/devkits online for sale on websites like Ebay I see them all the time, but technically a Custom Firmware Retail unit can do nearly most if not Everything a Developer unit cant. all you need is to unsandbox the system!